# Filtering content before loading cells

Tags: swift, filter, protocols

I got data models that I would need to filter before loading the cells. The have the following structure:

```
struct Food: Decodable {
 let title: String?
 let content: [Category]?
}

struct Category: Decodable {
 let title: String?
 let items: [FoodItem]?
}

struct FoodItem: Decodable {
 let title: String?
 let image: URL?
 let summary: String?
}
```

I load them on a `UICollectionView`. I want only contents that has `title`, `image` & `summary`. I can filter  the Category with items. How do I propagate across the entire `Food` data model. I can technically `for` loop this. I was wondering I could add a generic protocol/function to each model to achieve the same.

Filter items with

```
var filteredItem: Bool {
   return title != nil && summary != nil && image != nil
}
```

Comment: Not clear what's the question. Do you want get a flat list of FoodItem from all Categories?

Comment: I was looking at fetching a 2D array for content in `Food` whose items has title, image and summary but not nil values. Filter out FoodItems

Comment: Only partially related but why is everything optional? In practice is there a food without title and content? And the arrays should be empty but not optional. The only property which could be optional is `image` and maybe `summary`.

Comment: I agree but swiftlint expects decodables to be optionals. The server might not return the right data.

Comment: SwiftLint is an unnecessary nitpicker. And if the server changes the data format you will get an error which actually causes the same user experience as displaying nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what are you looking for is the [`filter(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) method, and you could use like this:

I'd consider that you have an array of `Food`, so you want to filter it as each food's `content` (`[Category]`) has to contain `items` (`[FoodItem]`) with non-nil properties:

```
// arr: [Food]
let filteredFood = arr.filter { food -> Bool in
    var bool = false
    food.content?.forEach { $0.items?.forEach({ foodItem in
        bool = foodItem.title != nil && foodItem.summary != nil && foodItem.image != nil
    })}
    return bool
}
```